# Как в Т4 сгенерировать простой класс?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

Как в Т4 сгенерировать простой класс?

Создаю Т4 - жму Ран кастом тул, и оно генерит какой-то рабочий класс в стиле:

```
#line hidden
/// <summary>
/// Create the template output
/// </summary>
public virtual string TransformText()
```

Как сделать, чтобы было наподобие T4MVC, только уже готовые классы.

Для примера: чтоб Т4 создал три класса с полем `int testField {get; set;}`.

UPD.
http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/how-to-generate-multiple-output-files-from-a-single-t4-template.html

Comment: Руками, всё руками. А что в вашем .t4-файле?

Comment: Что руками? Допустим, мне надо, чтоб Т4 создал три класса с полем int testField {get; set;}. Как быть?

Comment: @sss: Ну так покажите, что есть.

T4 умеет всё, но он работает не на том уровне. Он генерирует текстовый файл, а будет в этом файле исходник класса или «Война и мир», зависит лично от вас. Ща сварганю хелловорлд вам.

Comment: "<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>"

Просто чистый шаблон. Тоесть, Т4 генерит калсс, мтодами которого можно сгенерить что угодно? Как тогда построенны всякие EF модель генераторы и Т4МВС? У наих структура немного инная - в самом .тт файле правила автогенирования и все и как-то онос разу создает все.

Comment: @sss: Ну, там ещё, небось, подключаются внешние .t4-файлы, которые, используя модельные структуры как описание, генерируют код.

Comment: @VladD, все сложней, значит. Как тогда разобраться с этим, в какую сторону копать? Цель та же - автогенерированные классы в отдельных файлах по кнопашке РАн Кастом Тул.

Comment: @sss: Run Custom Tool вам выбирать не надо — T4 перестраивает файлы на лету, сразу после сохранения .tt-файла в IDE. Для вашей задачи вам нужно написать руками кодогенератор (то есть, генератор .cs  с классами), управляемый конфигурацией, положить его его как .ttinclude, в каждый .tt положить конфигурацию и заинклюдить генератор. И фсё, по идее.

(По модулю того, что «написать конфигурируемый кодогенератор» — задача не на две минуты.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4 умеет всё, но он работает не на том уровне. Он генерирует текстовый файл, а будет в этом файле исходник класса или «Война и мир», зависит лично от вас.

Генерация классов делается примерно так:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

<# var classNames = new[] { "ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC" };
   foreach (var name in classNames)
   {
#>

public class <#= name #>
{
    public int TestField { get; set; }
}

<# } #>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но после Ран Кастом тул файлов не появилось, изменился только test.сs для test.tt. Возможно, я что-то упускаю, но по примерам готовых тулзовин я ожидал создания вложенных классов.

Comment: @sss: Ну да. А в `test.cs` должен появиться код для трёх классов. Появился?

---
test.cs — это и есть то, куда происходит вывод, и где (по умолчанию) появляется сгенерированный код.

---
test.cs по идее автоматом включается в проект, так что сгенерированные классы доступны сразу.

Comment: @VladD, http://pastebin.com/yQVpXuDG вот это вот появилось.

Comment: @sss: У меня всё работает (ц)

<http://i.imgur.com/1zRGQXZ.png>, <http://i.imgur.com/TiQumWQ.png>

А у вас Custom Tool правильно выбран?
____
@sss: Вы, небось, выбрали "Run-time template" вместо "Design-time template"? Перевыберите.

Comment: @VladD, да, был препроцессор в конфиге вместо генератора. Спасибо.

Comment: @sss: А, вот и хорошо, одной загадкой меньше.