# Как для всех обобщений метода сразу указать их ссылочный тип?

Tags: c#, generics

Метод Get будет перегружен до 10 параметров (из обобщений), каждый раз для каждого параметра прописывать, что он ссылочного типа - не удобно и это нагромождает код. Как собственно для всех сразу обобщений указать их ссылочный тип?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        public void Get<T, U, V>(out T valueT, out U valueU, out V valueV) where T : class where U : class where V : class
    {
        valueT = default(T);
        valueU = default(U);
        valueV = default(V);
    }
```

Я делаю игру в unity, часть логики уже написана и сейчас начали вылазить косяки организации взаимодействия логики и данных. К примеру, есть некий обьект (класс, к примеру StandartCube) он наследуется от базового(к примеру Actor). Поведение обьекта собирается в производном классе из перечисления набора компонентов(тоже классы). Эти компоненты содержат исходные данные(нужны для работы компонента) и логику. Так вот некоторые данные для разных компонентов могут быть общими. Чтобы в каждом компоненте не дублировать данные (особенно проблемно, если данные типа - значения), я решил их разбить на мелкие кусочки и обернуть в класс, и положить их в словарь типа object. Сам словарь находится в Actor, поэтому из компонента я всегда могу обратиться к методу Get… который дергает из словаря обьект типа object, привожу к нужному типу данных и возвращаю результат. Далее, если другому обьекту нужны данные StandartCube, я просто получаю Actor и также через Get получаю данные. Отсюда обобщения в Get это просто те классы с данными, которые меня интересуют. В некоторых моментах это напоминает ecs, но ввиду отсутствия опыта работы с ecs и уже написанной части логики, не рискну переходить на него.

Comment: Вместо `class` словов `object`

Comment: При where T : object - ошибка - ограничение не может быть специальным классом object. К тому же, это не решает проблемы, что для каждого параметра нужно указывать where...

Comment: `default( наследник_от_object)` всегда даст null. Там надо через активатор или конструктор создавать.

Comment: Если вы смирились с неудобством прописывать 10 перегрузок, то уж и смиритесь с неудобством прописывать каждый констрейнт. Я бы порекомендовал генерировать код методов, а не писать вручную (да хотя бы с помощью [того же T4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/369108/10105)).

Comment: Про default(T) я в курсе, у меня ниже в логике есть прерывание выполнения метода, а out параметры к тому времени должны быть инициализированы хоть как-то.

Comment: А зачему вам это нужно? Есть ещё вариант implicit/explicit cast. Покажите как вы хотите ваш Get использовать, и какого рода обьекты будете принимать. И у вас есть EF (Entity framework) там похожее на ваше есть.

Comment: @nick_n_a, сюда текст не влез, написал в описании темы

Comment: А вам нормально писать слева вместо var имя класа, или присваивать результ из словаря в переменную детерминированого типа? Если вас это устраиваtn - я предлагаю использовать  `public static implicit operator Actor(КлассПрослойка v)` и  `public static implicit operator StandartCube(КлассПрослойка v)`. Тогда каждый случай из словаря сам заберёт тот класс который ему нужен. Если вам не понятно как это сделать -  я распишу подробнее. Т.е. в итоге вы просто сможете писать типа `Actor act = dict[index];` и `StandartCube cub = dict[index2];` благодаря implicit, и будет + немного памяти "на удобства"